# SQL Server 2008 exec stored procedure on 3rd strike

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've been asked to create a process that triggers a stored procedure when an employee hits their 3rd strike. The strikes relate to absence, so if an employee is off 3 times in a 3 month period it hits the trigger.

But... **this only applies** to single instances of absence, so if a person is off; for example on the 11/01/2016, 12/01/2016 & 13/01/2016 then this is one instance. Meaning I can't do a count on the number of days off sick.

Data I have available and is a fixed process I can't update:

```
Date        | EmpID | EmpName
01/01/2016  | JS01  | John Spartan
02/01/2016  | JS01  | John Spartan
03/01/2016  | JS01  | John Spartan
08/01/2016  | JS01  | John Spartan
19/02/2016  | JS01  | John Spartan
12/02/2016  | JS01  | John Spartan
```

Based on the above there are more than 2 instances. So this would trigger the procedure

```
IF EXISTS (<Query Here>)
BEGIN
    EXEC usp_ThreeStrikes
END
```

Is there a way to do this in T-SQL?

Answer (score 0):

If you can't add columns to help query with the task (eg. InstanceID query would group by to find out number of instances), I think best solution would be to create aggregate CLR function for the task.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131056.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below approach:

1. Add an additional column to your table to differentiate if the record should be considered for next strike or not (means after 1 instance, it should not be considered the 2nd time)
2. Create a SQL Update Trigger to call the procedure, based on the below condition:

   - Get the records whose column is considered for next strike (same column what you have created in first step)
   - For those particular records check the count if its greater or equal to 3 and call the stored procedure
   - For those particular records, update the additional column (created in step 1) to not consider it for the subsequent strikes

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a query that lists the `empid`'s that were absent three or more times per quarter. You can modify this query in your trigger to only select in the empids/quarters that are present in the `inserted` table in your trigger.

PS: I've added some random absences to show that the query only selectes when the number of absences is three or more.

---

```
CREATE TABLE #absences(dt DATE,empid NVARCHAR(128),empname NVARCHAR(128));
INSERT INTO #absences(dt,empid,empname)VALUES
    ('20151212','JS02','John Spartan2'),
    ('20151213','JS02','John Spartan2'),
    ('20151010','JS01','John Spartan'),
    ('20151011','JS01','John Spartan'),
    ('20151217','JS02','John Spartan2'),
    ('20151219','JS02','John Spartan2'),
    ('20160101','JS01','John Spartan'),
    ('20160102','JS01','John Spartan'),
    ('20160103','JS01','John Spartan'),
    ('20160108','JS01','John Spartan'),
    ('20160201','JS02','John Spartan2'),
    ('20160203','JS02','John Spartan2'),
    ('20160219','JS01','John Spartan'),
    ('20160212','JS01','John Spartan');

SELECT
    empid,
    [quarter]=DATEADD(QUARTER,DATEDIFF(QUARTER,0,o.dt),0)
FROM    
    #absences AS o
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM #absences AS i
        WHERE i.empid=o.empid AND
              DATEDIFF(QUARTER,0,i.dt)=DATEDIFF(QUARTER,0,o.dt) AND
              i.dt=DATEADD(DAY,-1,o.dt)
    )
GROUP BY
    empid,
    DATEDIFF(QUARTER,0,o.dt)
HAVING
    COUNT(*)>=3;

DROP TABLE #absences;
```

Result:

```
+-------+-------------------------+
| empid |         quarter         |
+-------+-------------------------+
| JS02  | 2015-10-01 00:00:00.000 |
| JS01  | 2016-01-01 00:00:00.000 |
+-------+-------------------------+
```